# Is there a more elegant way to filter the failed results of a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For now I have something in my code that looks like this:

```
def f(x):
    if x == 5:
        raise ValueError
    else:
        return 2 * x

interesting_values = range(10)
result = []
for i in interesting_values:
    try:
        result.append(f(i))
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

`f` is actually a more complex function and it fails for specific values in an unpredictible manner (I can't know if `f(x)` will fail or not before trying it).

What I am interested in is to have this `result`: the list of all the valid results of `f`.

I was wondering if there is a way to make the second part like a list comprehension. Of course I can't simply do this:

```
def f(x):
    if x == 5:
        raise ValueError
    else:
        return 2 * x

interesting_values = range(10)
result = [f(i) for i in interesting_values]
```

because the call for `f(5)` will make everything fail, but maybe there is a way to integrate the try-except structure in a list comprehension. Is it the case?

EDIT: I have control over f.

Comment: can you return a sentinel value (e.g `None`) instead of throwing an exception?

Comment: I accepted @Carcigenicate's answer because I have indeed control over f and the other answers assume I don't. However I greatly appreciate everyone's explanation about sentinel values.

Comment: @AnneAunyme While I certainly appreciate the acceptance, I'll just note that you don't need to accept the answer that assumed correctly (since, ideally, all three of us should have waited for clarification of the cicumstances instead of making guesses... whoops). You can accept whatever answer you feel helped you out the most.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Your answer helped me solving the issue described here, but the other ones will help me the next time I face the issue they assumed I have (I have already faced it and I am pretty sure I will face it again). I think yours deserves to be accepted but the other ones are great and people who look for the assumed issue will be happy to see them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you have control of `f` and can modify how it handles errors.

If that's the case, and `None` isn't a valid output for the function, I would have it return `None` on an error instead of throwing:

```
def f(x):
    if x == 5: return None
    else: return 2*x
```

Then filter it:

```
results = (f(x) for x in interesting_values) # A generator expression; almost a list comptehension

valid_results = filter(lambda x: x is not None, results)
```

This is a stripped down version of what's often referred to as the "Optional Pattern". Return a special sentinal value on error (`None` in this case), else, return a valid value. Normally the Optional type is a special type and the sentinal value is a subclass of that type (or something similar), but that's not necessary here.

Comment: I'd recommend making `results` into a generator (just use parentheses instead of brackets) and `valid_results` into a list instead of the other way around, to conserve memory in the intermediate steps.

Comment: Also, fun fact, `lambda x: x is not None` can be `None.__ne__`

Comment: @MadPhysicist You gotta love the fluent readability though (even if "`lambda`" is a overly verbose).

Comment: @MadPhysicist And yes, good call. No point in having the whole thing in memory at once. I'm not sure `valid_results` needs to be realized right away though. Further filtering may be done of it. I'd just force it when absolutely necessary.

Comment: `map(f, interesting_values)` is also an option if you are going to use `filter` instead of `[x for x in results if x is not None]`

Comment: Just so we're clear, I'm just nitpicking because it's late and I have nothing else to do. I +1'd you a while back.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Ya, I always get yelled at when I use `map` instead of a comprehension though because apparently the overhead of `lambda` is non-insignificant. I like the readability of a `filter` over a filtered comprehensions though, so I dig in my heels a bit there. I find that a near empty comprehension with a guard looks off, but that could be lack of exposure on my part. And I know :P. I appreciate feedback as Python isn't my main language, and I don't want to leave unidiomatic suggestions up.

Comment: Honestly, you're in the gray area where it's all Pythonic enough and just a matter of taste. I'm just putting alternatives in the comments because they shouldn't clutter your actual post.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to assume here that you have no control over the source of `f`. If you do, the first suggestion is to simply rewrite `f` not to throw exceptions, as it's clear that you are expecting that execution path to occur, which by definition makes it not *exceptional*. However, if you don't have control over it, read on.

If you have a function that might fail and want its "failure" to be ignored, you can always just wrap the function

```
def safe_f(x):
  try:
    return f(x)
  except ValueError:
    return None

result = filter(lambda x: x is not None, map(safe_f, values))
```

Of course, if `f` could return `None` in some situation, you'll have to use a different sentinel value. If all else fails, you could always go the route of defining your own `_sentinel = object()` and comparing against it.

Comment: Actually I have control over this function, but now I inderstand why I shouldn't throw an exception in this case.

Answer (score 4):

You could add another layer on top of your function. A decorator if you will, to transform the exception into something more usable. Actually this is a function that returns a decorator, so two additional layers:

```
from functools import wraps

def transform(sentinel=None, err_type=ValueError):
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def func(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return f(*args, **kwargs)
            except err_type:
                return sentinel
        return func
    return decorator

@transform()
def f(...): ...

interesting = range(10)
result = [y for y in (f(x) for x in interesting) if y is not None]
```

This solution is tailored for the case where you get `f` from somewhere else. You can adjust `transform` to return a decorator for a given set of exceptions, and a sentinel value other than `None`, in case that's a valid return value. For example, if you import `f`, and it can raise `TypeError` in addition to `ValueError`, it would look like this:

```
from mystuff import f, interesting

sentinel = object()
f = transform(sentinel, (ValueError, TypeError))(f)
result = [y for y in (f(x) for x in interesting) if y is not sentinel]
```

You could also use the functional version of the comprehension elements:

```
result = list(filter(sentinel.__ne__, map(f, interesting)))
```